# Is there an effective tab manager for Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extensions

I've tried a few extensions but I wasn't very satisfied, I'm basically looking for an extension that allows me to group sets of tabs in such a way that I'm able to quickly switch between the groups within the same window. That is to say, if I had 5 Wikipedia tabs and 5 Stack Exchange tabs, ideally I would create 2 groups, hide the tabs of one of them, and switch between the Wikipedia and Stack Exchange tabs back and forth as I need without leaving the same window (note that I'm not specifically looking for grouping by site, that was just a simplified example)

Does an extension like this exist?

PS: No, I don't actually have 5 Wikipedia tabs open while browsing Stack Exchange sites :-)

Comment: Why the downvote? I did search before asking, the reason I ask is because I could not find any that meets what I describe.

Comment: Probable reason for down vote is that we basicly don't do software recommendations any more [read some discussion on it](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/4622/why-was-my-software-rec-question-closed)

Comment: @Nifle I see, I noticed many questions like these in past at SU, hence why I didn't think it was not welcome.

Answer (score 1):

How could that be implemented ? You already have the **ctrl+tab** to naviguate quickly between tabs, you would need another shortcut to naviguate between tab groups... It's already possible.

The solution I think of is to manage your windows groups by browser windows instead. According to your exemple, you would split wiki and so on two different windows and then you got **alt+tab** to switch between groups and **ctrl+tab** to switch between websites tabs. It's simple !

Comment: You would be surprised how fast does the windows (7) taskbar clutter while working on a large project, even if the windows are grouped by application. If I could show/hide chrome windows on demand I suppose that could also work.

Comment: Do you know the reduce shortcut ? alt+space and press n it's very usefull

Comment: Now all we need is an option to move a group of tabs to their own window.